# Jdeveloper shows an unreachable statement

Tags: try-catch, jdeveloper

I already have been reviewing some questions related to the warning when we place a return in the finally block so I've changed it into the try or after the finally but it shows: Error: unreachable statement.

I really will appreciate if maybe you can check my code and see if something should be changed or replaced:

```
public ArrayList createUserList()throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException{
        ArrayList<User> userList= new ArrayList<User>();
        User user1;
         try {    
                InputFile = OpenInputFile(FilePath);
                while( true ){
                    user1 = (User)InputFile.readObject();                  
                    userList= (user1);`
                }
                return userList;`

            }catch(IOException ex ){throw ex; 
            }finally{

                closeInputFile(InputFile); 
            //return userList;
        }     
      }
```

*It may help:*

I'm working with **ObjectImputStream**,**ObjectOutputStream** and the **Serializable**, this is the code where the object is being read from a txt file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add the code here instead of providing external links. If it's a lot, you can try putting only the relevant part of it here.

Comment: From your screenshot it quite normal since you use while(true){...} which will result in an infinite loop. But I the line above the while statement is also weird... unless you don't follow the 'normal' naming conventions.

Comment: Hi! I just added the code, check it out and let's see what you think. Regarding the while(true) it's the only way to load the object that is being read from the Input File. If there's no Object to load or all the objects in the file were loaded from it. So it will change to false. My concern is about the **return statement** due as you can see there, a return shouldn't be in the finally block but since I changed it into the try it shows this error